# How to query specific adapters in Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface?

Tags: performance, networking, wmi

How can I query specific adapters (ideally based on the IP address) from `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`? I've spent a while googling this issue, but I didn't come up with a solution.

I tried using `Win32_NetworkAdapter` and `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`, however, I cannot link these to the performance data.

As I happen to have more than one network adapter on certain systems, I cannot differentiate which adapter the returned values belong to - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
            ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
            scope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface");

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Current Bandwidth: {0}", queryObj["CurrentBandwidth"]);
            }
```

My output was

Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller - Packet Scheduler Miniport
Current Bandwidth: 100000000
Name: MS TCP Loopback interface
Current Bandwidth: 10000000
Press any key to continue . . .

Similar to this you can enhance the properties of this Win32_ class

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately that does not help me - I already tried to use the "Name" property, however, I cannot rely on it and I also cannot relate it to an adapter's ip-address. The "Name" property does have more or less random vendor specific contents, and it may be quite different for various servers and network adapters. So your suggestion works okay for a single system where I know which adapter is which, but as I have to query a lot of different servers I would ideally need the adapter's ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

1. Query for the instances of Win32_NetworkAdapter that you are interested in.
2. Take the value of 'PNPDeviceID' from each Win32_NetworkAdapter and append it to "\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\" to produce a registry path to information on the adapter.  Here is an example: "\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_100E&SUBSYS_001E8086&REV_02\3&267A616A&0&18".
3. Query the registry for the "FriendlyName" key at the path you derived above.
4. If the "FriendlyName" key is present then take its string value.  If the "FriendlyName" key is not defined then instead use the value of the "Description" key from Win32_NetworkAdapter.
5. Take the string you got in step #4 and replace all instances of "/" and "#" with an underscore "_".
6. The resulting string from step #5 should match the "Name" property within Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface.