# Network statistics for an adapter identified by IP

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to monitor network statistics for a specific adapter with powershell. The monitoring process itself works well and it is based on `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`

My problem is to select the correct interface to monitor by the IP Address. The code above does not contain this information so I started to use other commands which include the address and I tried to find a relationship. But currently without success.

No index, name, description or any other strings are unique. I'm pretty sure that there must be something but I can't find it. :/

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I've found an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813937/how-to-query-specific-adapters-in-win32-perfformatteddata-tcpip-networkinterface) here with exaclty the same problem. It's a few years old but still without a reliable solution.

**EDIT 2**

I've created a workarround without accessing the Win32 class directly. Anyway, I'm still interested in a solution for my initial question.

```
$myIp = "192.168.1.101"

$myCurrentBytes = Get-NetAdapterStatistics | Where-Object -Property InterfaceAlias -eq `
                (Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object -Property IPAddress -eq  $myIp | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias).InterfaceAlias `
                 | Select-Object -Property ReceivedBytes,SentBytes

$myCurrentKbytesDown = [math]::Round($myCurrentBytes.ReceivedBytes / 1024)
$myCurrentKbytesUp = [math]::Round($myCurrentBytes.SentBytes / 1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use filter.

Here:

```
$SourceIP = '192.168.100.1' #specify IP you want
$Name = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where { $_.IPAddress -contains $SourceIP } | Select -ExpandProperty Description
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -Filter "Name='$Name'"
```

Comment: If you add a 2nd adapter of the same type you will get e.g. `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller _2` from AdapterConfiguration and `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2` from NetworkInterface.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Why would you set two interfaces with same IP address?

Comment: I don't want to use the same IP on multiple interfaces. Your code uses the description/name to identify the adapter but it MUST also work on machines with multiple adaptors of the same type. Then windows starts to add a trailing number to each adapter and the syntax is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows 2012:

```
$myIp = "192.168.100.1"

$myCurrentBytes = Get-NetIPAddress $myIp | Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetAdapterStatistics | Select-Object -Property ReceivedBytes,SentBytes

$myCurrentKbytesDown = [math]::Round($myCurrentBytes.ReceivedBytes / 1024)
$myCurrentKbytesUp = [math]::Round($myCurrentBytes.SentBytes / 1024)
```

Basically, find the IP address first and then pipe that to get the adapter and then pipe that to get the adapter statistics.